# required android.support.v4.app.fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

i have simple project that have list view 
when any one click on any item on list view 
open in single window
by fragment 
the problem is that i want to replace my fragment with on of this tabs fragment on this project 
http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/

i put my mainactivty class in switch case but it get to me this error
in first picture 
i try to import import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
but also the same promplem

this is the clases of my project 
....Main2Activity class

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements fragmentA.comunicatir
        {

        fragmentA f1;
        fragmentB f2;
        FragmentManager manegaer;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

                manegaer=getSupportFragmentManager();
        f1=(fragmentA)manegaer.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
        f1.setcomunicatir(this);
        }


        @Override
        public void respned(int index){
                f2=(fragmentB)manegaer.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);

        if(f2!=null&&f2.isVisible()){

        f2.cahngedata(index);
        }else{
        Intent intent=
        new Intent(this,
        AnotherActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("index",index);
        startActivity(intent);
        }


        }
        }
```

[image: error 2]

the another classes 
class fragmentA

```
 public class fragmentA extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{
    ListView list;
    comunicatir  com;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,container,false);
        list=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.chapters, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        return  view;

    }

    public void setcomunicatir (comunicatir comunicator)
    {

        this.com=comunicator;
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View veiw, int i, long l) {

        com.respned(i);

    }


    public interface comunicatir
    {
        public void respned(int index);

    }
}

    public class fragmentB  extends Fragment

{

    TextView text;
    TextView textView2;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
        //text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        //imgv=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        textView2 =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView22);

        return view;

    }
    public void cahngedata(int index)
    {

    /*String[] descrption =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hadeith);
            text.setText(descrption[index]);*/

        String []Hadith=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hadeith);
        //imgv.setImageResource(img[index]);
        textView2.setText(Hadith[index]);

        //int []descrption =getResources().getIntArray(img[index]);
        //  imgv.setImageResource(descrption[index]);       

            /*text.setText(descrption[index]);
        int arr[]=getResources().getIntArray(img[index]);
            imgv.setImageResource(arr[index]);*/


    }
}



public class AnotherActivity extends Activity

{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.another);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int index= intent.getIntExtra("index", 0);
        fragmentB f2= (fragmentB)
                getFragmentManager().
                        findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
        if (f2!=null)
            f2.cahngedata(index);

    }
}
```

the Another Activity class also have error in picture 2

[image: error 2]

Answer (score 0):

**1st issue:** You just can't put an activity on a Tab, but you probably won't need the getItem() you can delete that method

**2nd issue:**

Replace:

```
fragmentB f2 = (fragmentB) ...
```

With:

```
fragment f2 = (Fragment) ...
```

Comment: getItem()  cannot delete because it is implantation method

Comment: Just put "return new Tab1()" on it. It doesn't matter if you wont use it

Comment: ok but it not display my Main2Activity i try to chang Main2Activity  to extend fragment  see this photo https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByZGzcCum73xQ0trVEh3cmhiNHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You are right. In your intent replace "this" with "getActivity()"

Comment: thank you for your understanding  i change all my activities to extend from fragment  ... but in method    onItemClick in fragmentA   till me this error  (( java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                        at com.example.ibrahim.androidtablayout.listviewfragment.fragmentA.onItemClick(fragmentA.))

Answer (score 0):

go to the tab.class which u have problem in and change 
import android.app.Fragment;
to
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

it will run .